# Call nav functions from a sub Knockout ViewModel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I'm Building a Single Page Application using ASP.NET MVC, Knockout, nav.js...etc.,

Two View Model:

1. FatherViewModel;
2. SonViewModel;

FatherViewModel has All the Navigation methods, 
FatherViewModel has an instance of SonViewModel,

**Q: How to access those Navigation methods from the SonViewModel?**

```
FatherViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var dataSource = {...}

    self.sonViewModel = new SonViewModel();

    self.nav = new NavHistory({
        params: {...},
        onNavigate: function (navEntry) {...}
    }).initialize({ linkToUrl: true });
    //navigation methods:
    self.gotoHomePage = function (){...}
}
SonViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var dataSource = {...}

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the father's methods from the son viewmodel, you need to pass a reference of the father to the son, like so:

```
FatherViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var dataSource = {...}

    self.sonViewModel = new SonViewModel(self);

    self.nav = new NavHistory({
        params: {...},
        onNavigate: function (navEntry) {...}
    }).initialize({ linkToUrl: true });
    //navigation methods:
    self.gotoHomePage = function (){...}
}
SonViewModel = function (father) {
    var self = this;
    self.father = father;
    var dataSource = {...}

    function gotoHomePage() {
        self.father.gotoHomePage();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: :), OK you got it...But it's not what I'm looking for, guess i Need to dig into Knockout much deeper...